# Are valve shims re-usable?

Tags: suzuki, valve, shim

I'm in the process of re-shimming the valves on my 1994 Suzuki Katana 600.  For the valves where I need to replace the shim, should I save the old shim I removed, or is it considered a disposable item once used?

The ones I'm removing visually appear to be in perfect shape despite being quite old.  I get a reasonable measurement from them as well (new ones going in are labeled 2.70 and measure 2.72, these ones I pulled measure 2.87 just like the 2.85s in my kit).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, shims are reusable. Since they are between two pieces of metal and suffer no fatigue or wear, as long as they look good and measure out good (are concentric), there should be no issue using them. Even the measurement on them is sort of arbitrary, because it's the end result you're looking for. In many cases you can shift your shims around to get the proper clearances when replacing springs or doing valve work. It's the end result which matters most. How you get there can involve old shims or new ... it doesn't matter.